# are there any ways to use send or recv temporarily in blocking mode when the socket is set non-blocking

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

if a socket is set  non-blocking,

but at a certain moment, I want to use send or recv with this socket in blocking mode,

can I temporarily sent it as blocking mode and then recover to non-blocking.

if so, how about the other way around? use send or recv temporarily in non-blocking mode if the socket is in blocking mode?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fcntl()` with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag.

Use it to set the socket the blocking mode, send(or recv) your data and use `fcntl` again to set to the socket the non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 2):

> can I temporarily sent it as blocking mode and then recover to non-blocking.

Yes, of course, just use FIONBIO the other way round.

> if so, how about the other way around? use send or recv temporarily in non-blocking mode if the socket is in blocking mode?

Yes, of course. There are two ways to do that: with FIONBIO or with the MSG_DONTWAIT flag to recv().

Comment: @misteryes Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150635/unix-nonblocking-i-o-o-nonblock-vs-fionbio) about FIONBIO and O_NONBLOCK

Comment: Ｉ don't get it when you say FIONBIO can set a non-blocking socket temporarily to blocking mode.

Comment: It's not temporarily with FIONBIO, it acts like O_NONBLOCK. that means you have to call `ioctl()` before and after the `recv()`/`send()`, just like  `fcntl()` (which is a POSIX function, so you should use it instead of `ioctl()`)

Comment: I don't see what there is not to get. FIONBIO is used to set or clear non-blocking mode. Or O_NONBLOCK.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the mode, or you could just use `select()` or `epoll()` to detect when a socket is readable/writable before performing a `recv/send()` that would normally block, or to simulate blocking behavior by reading/sending in a loop while the intended data is still pending.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as already has been said, you can of course change the state whenever you want with the `fcntl()` call. However I don't really understand the requirement, because when you implement a non blocking algorithm, you can of course make it appear as if it were blocking by simply looping. 
And you will need a protocoll anyway, so this seems to me as if you were relying on some particular behaviour.