# solaris: O_NDELAY set on stdin: when process exits the shell exits

Tags: solaris, fcntl

TLDR: **In Solaris**, if `O_NDELAY` is set on `stdin` by a *child process*, `bash` exits.  Why?

The following code causes interactive `bash` (v4.3.33) or `tcsh` (6.19.00) shells to exit after the process finishes running:

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  fcntl( 0, F_SETFL, O_NDELAY );

//int x = fcntl( 0, F_GETFL );
//fcntl( 0, F_SETFL, ~(x ^ (~O_NDELAY)) );

  return 0;
}
```

The versions of `ksh`, `csh` and `zsh` we have aren't affected by this problem.

To investigate I ran `bash` & `csh` under `truss` (similar to `strace` on Linux) like this:

```
$ truss -eaf -o bash.txt -u'*' -{v,r,w}all bash --noprofile --norc
$ truss -eaf -o csh.txt -u'*' -{v,r,w}all csh -f
```

After `csh` finishes running the process it does the following:

```
fcntl( 0, F_GETFL ) = FWRITE|FNDELAY
fcntl( 0, F_SETFL, FWRITE) = 0
```

... which gave me an idea.  I changed the program to the commented out code above so it would toggle the state of `O_NDELAY`.  If I run it twice in a row bash doesn't exit.

Comment: Well, I would certainly not be surprised if the shell gets very confused by having the terminal unexpectedly put in non-blocking mode.  Why are you doing that?  This seems like a "don't do that, then".

Comment: In particular, it means that when the shell next tries to read the terminal, instead of blocking to wait for input, the `read()` call will fail immediately.  There's no particular reason the shell should be designed to handle this situation, and so it probably assumes there was a genuine error and gives up.  The shell on Linux may be written in a different way such that this happens not to break it (e.g. waiting for input using `poll()` instead of `read()`).

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: Well, *I'm* not the one doing it; it's a 3rd party tool.  The shell is bash v 4.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151077/549246) got me started on the right path.  The man page for `read` (in Solaris) says:

```
When attempting to read a file associated with a terminal that has no data currently available:

* If O_NDELAY is set, read() returns 0
* If O_NONBLOCK is set, read() returns -1 and sets errno to EAGAIN
```

... so when bash tries to read `stdin` it returns 0 causing it to assume EOF was hit.

[This page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-6331/6j5vgg6an/index.html) indicates `O_NDELAY` shouldn't be used anymore, instead recommending `O_NONBLOCK`.  I've found similar statements regarding `O_NDELAY` / `FIONBIO` for various flavors of UNIX.

As an aside, in Linux `O_NDELAY == FNDELAY == O_NONBLOCK`, so it's not terribly surprising I was unable to reproduce this problem in that environment.

Unfortunately, the tool that's doing this isn't one I have the source code for, though from my experimenting I've found ways to work around the problem.

If nothing else I can make a simple program that removes `O_NDELAY` as above then wrap execution of this tool in a shell script that always runs the "fixer" program after the other one.